# Lazy loading LWC without datatable and loadMore

Tags: lightning-web-components, lazy-loading

Let's say we have

```
<template>
<template if:false={isLoading}>
    <div class="cxd-history__container" onscroll={handleScroll}>
            <template for:each={historyList} for:item="historyItem">
                <div key={historyItem.emailName}>
                    <c-email-card payload={historyItem}></c-email-card>
                </div>
            </template>            
    </div>
</template>
<template if:true={isLoading}>
    <div class="cxd-loading-spinner">
        <lightning-spinner alternative-text="Loading" size="medium"></lightning-spinner>
      </div>
</template>
```

and controller is

```
export default class EmailHistory extends LightningElement {
@api recordId;
historyList = [];
isLoading = false;
page = 0;
connectedCallback() {
  this.loadMore();
}
handleScroll = (e) => {
    const target = e.target;
    if(target.scrollHeight - target.scrollTop <= target.clientHeight) {
        this.loadMore();
    }
}
loadMore = () => {
    if(this.isLoading) return;
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.page++;
    getNext({page: this.page, pageSize: PAGE_SIZE, accountId: this.recordId})
        .then(data => {
            this.historyList = [...this.historyList, ...JSON.parse(data)];
            this.isLoading = false;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('error',(error));
        })
        .finally(() => {
            this.isLoading = false;
        });
}
```

every time i scrolled it down i've got expected results but from the early beginning.
is that some workaround to simulate kinda 'loadMore` when it comes to lightning-datatatable?
(it isn't possible to use datatable in my case)

Answer (score 0):

Your `recordId` is likely not populated when `connectedCallback` is called. I know they say it should be, but I've found that it's often null at this point.

Use a getter/setter to handle this:

```
@api
get recordId() {
  return this._recordId;
}
  
set recordId(value) {
  this._recordId = value;
  this.getFirstPage();
}
```

You *COULD* use a wired function to handle this to call your data function, but it's easier to just call your data getter in the setter, as above.

`getFirstPage` just sets up the required params:

```
getFirstPage = () => {
    if(this.isLoading) return;
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.callGetNext(this.page,PAGE_SIZE,this.recordId);
}

callGetNext => (page, pageSize, accountId){
  getNext({page: page, pageSize: pageSize, accountId: accountId})
    .then(data => {
      this.historyList = [...this.historyList, ...JSON.parse(data)];
      this.isLoading = false;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('error',(error));
    });
}
```

`loadMore` is similar to get first page:

```
loadMore = () => {
    if(this.isLoading) return;
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.page++;
    this.callGetNext(this.page,PAGE_SIZE,this.recordId);
}
```

You would also entirely remove the `connectectedCallback`.
I think that'll do it.

Comment: I beleive that for:each matters so temolate is getting re-rendered each time onscroll got fired. Can you gutys suggest some workaround?